# Advantages of tag dispatching over normal overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Plain and simple: what's the advantage of tag dispatching over normal overload resolution?

These are both compile-time processes right? So there shouldn't be a 'performance winner' I suppose. And every tag dispatching case should be able, to some extent, to be rewritten/refactored into normal overloading (possibly by adding multiple types), right?

Aside from the different way of working and selecting candidates, why should I prefer tag dispatching over overload resolution and in which cases?

Comment: Tag based dispatching is achieved via overloading

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Tag dispatching` is basically a name given to a technique employed to find correct overloaded function. So, technically it is nothing but overloading only.

To put it from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) site:

> Tag dispatching is a way of using function overloading to dispatch
>   based on properties of a type, and is often used hand in hand with
>   traits classes.

You can see it used all over in you standard library `algorithm` header file. Just for the sake of an example, consider that there is an algorithm `AlgoX` which can be performed a lot more efficiently on a container providing random access (eg `vector`) than a container providing bidirectional access (`list`). So, for selecting the algorithm based on the `iterator type` one would use tag dispatching using `iterator_traits`

```
template <typename Iter>
void AlgoXImpl(Iter first, Iter last, bidirectional_iterator_tag) {
  //.....Algo specialized to bidirectional iterators
}

template <typename Iter>
void AlgoXImpl(Iter first, Iter last, random_access_iterator_tag) {
  //.....Algo specialized to random access iterators
}

template <typename Iter>
void AlgoX(Iter first, Iter last) {
  if (first == last) return;
  AlgoXImpl(first, last, typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
}
```

As you can see, to a simple mind this is nothing but an example of operator overloading as the categories are essentially different types.

For a more real world example, you can checkout out how `std::rotate` is implemented.

Comment: The fact that tag dispatching is heavily used does not at all answer the question why it is used. The OP correctly notes that its effects can be easily achieved by plain method overloading in type hierarchies under his control. So, the decisive argument really is to implement a custom dispatch scheme that is decoupled from the type definitions. See my answer below.

Comment: The gist of my answer is basically the first 4-5 lines, not that it is used in STL.

Comment: Big question to complement this answer: **is tag dispatching somewhat faster wrt normal overloading?** I suppose not since they're both implemented at compile-time, but I'm still asking.. just to be sure.

Comment: @Dean Yes, they are both implemented at compile time (unless we are talking about stored procedures or symbols in a shared library). Tag dispatching is just a name given to a particular use case of function overloading where we try to select the best overload by using some type trait.

Answer (score 2):

Tags can be associated with a type, even including basic primitive types, through appropriate trait classes. E.g., it would be impossible to make a pointer type a subclass of some iterator concept. However, a templated trait class may associate it with the desired tag. Thus, tag-based dispatching adds flexibility that allows to build a dispatch scheme that must not already be defined by the involved types.